# Improve pyautogui.press speed

Tags: python, ocr, opencv, pyautogui

I am writing an auto typing bot for 10fastfingers.com. It works.

I'm using pytesseract library to find text after that I use pyautogui to press key.
I recognize that pyautogui.press is not so fast.

And I am finding something like pyautoguide.press but having good speed.
Like [this video](https://vimeo.com/352072921)

```
from PIL import Image
import pyautogui
import time
import cv2
import pytesseract


class Cordinates():
    textbox = (80, 275)
    replayBtn = (800,450)
    whereitype = (250,460)
def restartGame():
    pyautogui.click(Cordinates.replayBtn)


def main():
    restartGame()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.click(Cordinates.whereitype)
    while True:
        pyautogui.screenshot('image.png')
        img = cv2.imread("image.png")
        crop_image = img[320:370, 80:940]
        cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_image)
        cv2.imwrite('cropped.png',crop_image)
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(crop_image, lang='eng')
        for c in text:
            print(c)
            if c == 'enter':
                    c=' '
            pyautogui.press(c)
            if pyautogui.position() == (1, 1):
                exit()
        pyautogui.press(' ')

main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looking into the script [https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/master/pyautogui/**init**.py](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/master/pyautogui/__init__.py)
`pyautogui.press`, by default, uses the 0.1 second `PAUSE` set globally in the module:

```
def press(keys, presses=1, interval=0.0, pause=None, logScreenshot=None, _pause=True):
    """Performs a keyboard key press down, followed by a release.
    ...
    ...
    _autoPause(pause, _pause)
```

_autoPause:

```
def _autoPause(pause, _pause):
    """If `pause` is not `None`, then sleep for `pause` seconds.
    If `_pause` is `True`, then sleep for `PAUSE` seconds (the global pause setting).
    This function is called at the end of all of PyAutoGUI's mouse and keyboard functions. Normally, `_pause`
    is set to `True` to add a short sleep so that the user can engage the failsafe. By default, this sleep
    is as long as `PAUSE` settings. However, this can be override by setting `pause`, in which case the sleep
    is as long as `pause` seconds.
    """
    if pause is not None:
        time.sleep(pause)
    elif _pause:
        assert isinstance(PAUSE, int) or isinstance(PAUSE, float)
        time.sleep(PAUSE)
```

and `PAUSE`:

```
PAUSE = 0.1 # The number of seconds to pause after EVERY public function call. Useful for debugging.
```

As you can see if pause in `press` is `None`, as it is by default, it reverts to the 0.1 second `PAUSE`.

You can override it, by setting a lower pause rate. `pyautogui.press(c, pause = 0.05)`